# How fix attack different ports in Ansible configuration?

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, automation

I have had a small problem that I did not find in the Ansible documentation, I would like to be able to attack several ssh ports with my playbooks, is there a way to tell Ansible that, apart from port 22, attack more ports?

It seems to me that the most logical thing would be to do it with variables in the Ansible playbooks, but I can't find too much information about this, does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: _More_ ports, or _different_ ports? As in, do you want to have Ansible try port 22, and then if it fails try something like 2222, and then if **that** fails, try 22222, and so on? Or do you just want certain hosts to use one single alternate port for SSH like 8080, while others use 2222, and yet others use the normal SSH port of 22?

Comment: Yes, specifically more ports, I have a problem, and that is that I have too many non-standard ports configured, and I would need to be able to indicate the 4 or 5 specific ports where I test the connection before finding the correct one, I think it is possible but I cannot find anything referring to the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add port into invertory:

```
[ping]
#ansible01
ansible01:8022
```

then:

```
[ping]
ansible01
#ansible01:8022
```

should change port.